# How to replace a partition in BQ using queries?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bq

I want to replace the latest partition on my BQ table with the already available data from an adhoc table.

Could anyone please help me in doing this?

The below command is not helping:

```
bq query \
--use_legacy_sql=false \
--replace \
--destination_table 'mydataset.table1$20160301' \
'SELECT
  column1,
  column2
FROM
  mydataset.mytable'
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use bq cp instead of bq query

From [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-tables#copying_partitions):

> To copy a partition, use the bq command-line tool's bq cp (copy)
> command with a partition decorator ($date) such as $20160201.
>
> Optional flags can be used to control the write disposition of the
> destination partition:
>
> **-a** or --append_table appends the data from the source partition to an existing table or partition in the destination dataset.
>
> **-f** or --force overwrites an existing table or partition in the destination dataset and doesn't prompt you for confirmation.
>
> **-n** or --no_clobber returns the following error message if the table or partition exists in the destination dataset: Table
> 'project_id:dataset.table or table$date' already
> exists, skipping. If -n is not specified, the default behavior is to
> prompt you to choose whether to replace the destination table or
> partition.

```
bq --location=location cp \ 
-f \
project_id:dataset.source_table$source_partition \
project_id:dataset.destination_table$destination_partition
```

So don't forget to use **-f** param to destroy old partition